# Error: Expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '<' token

Tags: c++

I have been trying for the last 20 minutes figuring out why it is throwing this error..

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <vector>

// global width and height
int GW;
int GH;

// current mouse position in pixel coordinate
int x;
int y;

typedef struct myTriangle {
   float tx;
   float ty;
} myTriangle;

vector<myTriangle> container;
```

The code throws this:

> Transform.cpp:17: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '<' token

Comment: Don't edit your source code with a word processor.  And use std::vector.

Answer (score 5):

Looks to me like you haven't specified the vector's namespace and haven't declared that you are using std::vector.  Try this instead:

```
std::vector<myTriangle> container;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it needs to be `std::vector`?